# C++: Weird behavior on method overloading

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

I need explanation about why the following code does not compile. I have a workaround which I will articulate below, but I don't understand the failure of the original version.

To speed up code reading: The concept is to define an interface (`ISomething`), then to create an abstract implementation (`ASomething`) which implements the second function `(2)` using the first (not yet defined) one `(1)`. A complete implementation which derives from the abstract one (for example `SomethingImpl`) must define the first method and has the option to override the second one.

```
#include <iostream>

class ISomething
{
public:
  virtual ~ISomething()
  { }
  virtual int f(int x) = 0; // (1)
  virtual int f(int x, int y) = 0; // (2)
};

class ASomething
  : public virtual ISomething
{
public:
  virtual int f(int x, int y) // (2)
  {
    return f(x) + f(y); // (3)
  }
};

class SomethingImpl
  : public ASomething
{
public:
  virtual int f(int x) // (1)
  {
    return x+1;
  }
};

int main()
{
  SomethingImpl a;
  std::cout << a.f(10) << std::endl; // (1)
  std::cout << a.f(10,20) << std::endl; // (2)
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling this code gives error on both Visual Studio 2013 (Windows) and g++ 4.4.5 (Linux). The errors are very similar, I will detail the g++ output only:

```
$ g++     SibFun.cpp   -o SibFun
SibFun.cpp: In member function ‘virtual int ASomething::f(int, int)’:
SibFun.cpp:18: error: no matching function for call to ‘ASomething::f(int&)’
SibFun.cpp:16: note: candidates are: virtual int ASomething::f(int, int)
SibFun.cpp:18: error: no matching function for call to ‘ASomething::f(int&)’
SibFun.cpp:16: note: candidates are: virtual int ASomething::f(int, int)
SibFun.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
SibFun.cpp:36: error: no matching function for call to ‘SomethingImpl::f(int, int)’
SibFun.cpp:26: note: candidates are: virtual int SomethingImpl::f(int)
make: *** [SibFun] Error 1
```

I tried to use different notation at `(3)` like `return this->f(x) + this->f(y)`, but I experienced no significant change in the error message.

However when I changed `(3)` to `return ISomething::f(x) + ISomething::f(y);` I only got:

```
$ g++     SibFun.cpp   -o SibFun
SibFun.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
SibFun.cpp:36: error: no matching function for call to ‘SomethingImpl::f(int, int)’
SibFun.cpp:26: note: candidates are: virtual int SomethingImpl::f(int)
make: *** [SibFun] Error 1
```

But! When change `(2)` from `f` to `g` all compiles and runs as expected.

What is the reason behind this begavior? Why can't I use the `f` name for `(2)`?

Comment: So why are you using virtual inheritance with class ASomething?  That is only needed if multiple inheritance is involved.

Comment: I cannot exclude that case so I always inherit interfaces virtually and never inherit implementations on multiple paths. Also, removing the `virtual` from the inheritance changes nothing.

Comment: @Jashaszun I included line numbers intentionally to help people finding the lines referenced in the compiler output.

Comment: @Notinlist Usual practice is to provide compilable code (i.e. without line numbers) and allow answerers to compile it themselves. They can also easily map errors to lines by putting it in, for example, Notepad++, which shows line numbers.

Comment: Why do you use `virtual` for overriding the methods? For MS VC++, either override using `virtual ... override` or without `virtual`.

Comment: @AlekseyF. I did not wanted to use `override`, because I wanted to be portable without using C++11. I used `virtual` because of copy-paste. It's not an error, not even a warning.

Comment: @Notinlist Yes, it's not an error, but a different meaning. It seems like the method defined with `virtual` in the derived class reintroduces that method rather than overrides the inherited, which should create a new record in the virtual method table. It is not needed to use C++11 for `override`: MS VC++ supports this keyword since MS VC 2005.

Comment: @AlekseyF. One compiler knowing `override` since 2005 does not matter to me. Can you demonstrate the difference between writing and not writing `virtual` when overriding? I couldn't find any reference for your claim.

Comment: @Notinlist Yes, you are right that manipulating with `virtual` or `override` does not fix the compile error.
MS VC 2005 compiles your code with error C2660, see the case ["C2660 will occur if a derived class hides a function"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek13fhc1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) at MSDN.
See also ["`sealed`, `abstract`, and `override` are also available in compilations that do not use /clr."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8ew2153%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) at MSDN.
My mistake is that I missed in my code `_MyB::`, i.e. scope resolution, in calls of derived methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both compilation failures happen for the same reason. While you're overriding one virtual member function, you're hiding the other. In `ASomething`:

```
virtual int f(int x, int y) // (2)
{
    return f(x) + f(y); // (3)
}
```

Name lookup on `f` finds `ASomething::f` and stops, it doesn't keep going to look for other overloads. Since `ASomething::f` takes two arguments, and you're trying to call it with one, error. In order to allow for overloading against the base class, you have to introduce the base class member functions with a *using-declaration*:

```
using ISomething::f; // NOW, ISomething::f(int ) is found by lookup

virtual int f(int x, int y)
{
    return f(x) + f(y);
}
```

And similarly, `SomethingImpl` needs a `using ASomething::f;` statement so that `a.f(10)` can compile.

Comment: This can also be accomplished by maintaining a [non-virtual interface that calls differently named virtual implementation functions](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9d11c4dde4bd92a), which has the added benefit of allowing you to use any intuitively accessible function from the interface without using declarations in the inheriting class definition.

Comment: @jaggedSpire Presumably if OP wanted to name the functions differently, OP would have named them differently.

Comment: Agreed. I figured someone might stumble on this question from Google for whom that would be a good solution, so I added it as a comment. It is your answer, though, so if you want me to remove it I happily will.

Answer (score 7):

Function overloading works only for functions visible in the same scope:

```
class ASomething
    : public virtual ISomething
{
public:
  virtual int f(int x, int y) // (2)
  {
    return f(x) + f(y); // (3)
  }

  using ISomething::f;
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
};

class SomethingImpl
   : public ASomething
{
public:
  virtual int f(int x) // (1)
  {
    return x+1;
  }    

  using ASomething::f;
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not an 'overloading' problem, but hiding a base class function (See other answers)

**A slightly modified example:**

```
#include <iostream>

class ISomething
{
    public:
    virtual ~ISomething() {}
    virtual int f(int x) = 0; // (1)
    virtual int f(int x, int y) = 0; // (2)
};

class ASomething: public virtual ISomething
{
    public:
    virtual int f(int x, int y) // (2)
    {
        // `this->f(x)` fails: 
        ISomething& i = *this;
        return i.f(x) + i.f(y); // (3)
    }
};

class SomethingImpl: public ASomething
{
    public:
    virtual int f(int x) // (1)
    {
        return x+1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    SomethingImpl a;
    // `a.f(10, 20)` fails:
    ISomething& i = a;
    std::cout << i.f(10) << std::endl; // (1)
    std::cout << i.f(10, 20) << std::endl; // (2)
    return 0;
}
```

Hence, calling `f` from the interface, resolves the conflict. Although, you should consider `using base::f`, as suggested in other answers.

Comment: You removed a crucial element when `ASomething::f` calls `ISomething::f` `(3)`.

Comment: I like your answer very much. Can I have an additional question? Isn't it bad that I inherit publicly and override a few things and the interface gets narrower? What is the rationale behind all this?